# What can my models bind to when a collection is reset?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Are there any events my models can bind to, to know their collection has been reset?

When I call:

```
collection.reset()
```

I want those removed models to be destroyed and in turn any views to know they are gone. What should I bind to here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mu's answer is correct, but you might also need to know that a model that is added to a collection has the `.collection` property, which points to the parent collection. So if you are instantiating your models manually, you can just do this:

```
var myModel = new MyModel();
collection.add(myModel);
collection.bind('reset', model.cleanUp(), model);
```

But if you're instantiating your models via the collection, e.g. with `collection.fetch()`, you need to bind to the collection in the `initialize()` method of the model:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        if (this.collection) {
            this.collection.bind('reset', this.cleanUp(), this);
        }
    }
    // etc
});
```

Comment: Very helpful, my question was perhaps not worded very well but this was the problem that I was trying to solve. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the [fine manual](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-reset):

> **reset** collection.reset(models, [options])
>   [...] triggering a single `"reset"` event at the end.

So bind to the collection's `reset` event and hope that no one uses the `{silent: true}` option to do things behind your back.